# Verify SQL file before use

Tags: php, mysql

I have php code I'm using to import a .sql file into a mysql database. The first thing the code does is check for the file and if it exists, then it drops several tables and imports the sql file (replacing the dropped tables). As you can imagine, one time the sql file was invalid, but the code marched on and dropped the tables. Is there a way to verify the validity of a sql file using php?

This needs to have some amount of automation for a couple of reasons. I don't always do the import. After the import, the code immediately uses the new tables to update/create/delete records in other tables. So I can't have a workflow where I stop the process to check if it was a success; I need a way for php to verify the success.

This is the code being used to import the sql file:

```
$templine = '';  
$lines = file($filename);  
foreach ($lines as $line) {  
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '') continue;  
    $templine .= $line;  
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {  
        $wpdb->query($templine);  
        $templine = '';  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Instead or dropping the table first, couldn't you just attempt to create the new table with a different name? If it succeeded then drop and rename, otherwise the file is bad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question to include why this wouldn't work for my current situation.

Comment: @ModusPonen you can do both his and my suggestion without stopping to manually check. Have the code do a query on a row or rows you expect to exists, and based on the result have the code respond accordingly

Comment: Yeah, I like the rename method. I was able to rename tables, import, check if they exist and go from there. Thought maybe there was some magic function that verified the validity a sql file or something, but this works good. Thanks.

Comment: *This is the code being used to import the sql file.*  That code is quite naïve, and that could contribute to your stability.  There is a significant amount of entirely valid SQL that it would not handle properly. It should, at a minimum, be modified to tolerate stray whitespace characters on a line before `--`, or after `;` when trying to contextualize each line.   To do this correctly, eliminating potentialy misfires of this code against valid SQL with nuances it fails to grasp, you really need the services of an SQL tokenizer library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I can think of two ways.

One approach is to have an alternative database to use as a test, connect to that database, import the sql into this database first, verify it worked with a query. If that passes, then connect to main database and proceed as usual.

A different approach is to export the existing database into a sql file. After importing the sql file, verify if it worked with a query, if not, import the old database with the exported sql file.

All of this can be automated to run in 1 step.

Comment: This worked with this suggestion and that of j08691 to rename the tables, perform the import, then check if the new tables exist, if good, drop the renamed tables, if bad, drop any new ones created during the import then rename the old tables back as they were. Thanks.